ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND in node express
I getting problem in running the index.js file threw nodemon.
whenever I run nodemon index.js in terminal it threw the module_not_found error.
I want that the error will resolve and index.js file successfully running on server.

can you please tell me about the node and express version?

Post the full error message! Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

You have to install nodemon NPM package global or as a dev dependency
To install Globaly
npm install -g nodemon

To install dev dependency
npm install --save-dev nodemon

Once you install it then you can run this command to execute you index.js file
nodemon ./index.js


If he had nodemon not installed, he would not receive a module_not_found error, rather than a "nodemon: command not found". More likely he had forgotten to install a dependency, But because he truncated the error message, its hard to tell what module is missing.
